# Can I use same keystore for New Application which will replace exiting application

Tags: android, android-market-filtering

I have one application in Google Play, Now I had developed one new Application to replace this current android application, Existing application and New Application has different Application Name, Package Name . So I just want to know that Can I use Existing application (Which is currently in market)  keystore for creating new application signed apk file?

My requirement is Existing user will gate alert that new version is available after updating user will get New Application on there device.

I dont want to maintain two seperate apk files (existing application which is in market and New one)

Comment: You need to use the same keystore file and package name .Then you can update the current app in playstore with your new file.ALso you need to increment the version code and name in manifest file .thanks

Comment: @ArunAntoney  If package Name is different then I can't use same keystore to update the apk?

Comment: @PPD it will not be considered as an update. Check my answer.

Comment: When an app installed on device its using its package name.So if you changed it will be a seprate app two app will install on users device.Also it will not override the current one in the playstore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`My requirement is Existing user will gate alert that new version is available`

To give users alert that a newer version is available you will have to keep the package name and signing key same and increase the app version number and version code.

`Can I use Existing application (Which is currently in market) keystore for creating new application signed apk file`

Yes. You can use same keystore to sign any number of applications you want.

But remember **signing an app (with different package name) with same keystore does not make it an update to existing app**. If package name is different, it will be treated as a brand new application.